# why this java code does not work?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have this code fragment

```
class bst {
  public node root=null;

  bst() {
    root=null;
  }

  public void insert(int data) {  
    insert(this.root,data);
  }

  private void insert(node ro,int data) {
    if (ro==null) {
      print ("root is null");
      ro=new node(data);
    } else if (data>ro.data)
      insert(ro.right,data); 
    else
      insert(ro.left,data);
  }

  private void print (String str) 
  {
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

When I call the `insert` function like `insert(5); insert(8);` it alwaty prints `root is null`.

whats the problem??

Comment: The next time, please make sure your post is readable. That code was a horrible mess and since you posted is as a quote you didn't even get syntax highlighting.

Comment: You should learn to better indent your code!

Comment: `insert` is not a function, it's a method.

Comment: Java is pass by value, not pass by reference.

Comment: method is a member function, anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that `ro` variable inside the `insert` method is just a copy of the reference to `bst.ro`. Meaning that if you **reset** the `ro` variable inside the method, just the copy of the reference will point the **new** `ro`, the originally passed object will remain the same.

Your question is the top 1 of Parameter Passing FAQ. I myself already answered this question more than once. [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931218/c-allocating-dynamic-memory-in-a-function-newbie-question/1931231#1931231).