# why C++ have a reference type "&"?

Tags: c++

C++ has already have pointer type, and  it is already very powerful,  but it also have reference type, whose most work can also be done by pointer, so what's the advantage of reference type? why C++'s creator added this type into it?

Comment: How about using arithmetic operators through pointers? `*a = *c + *d * *c`

Comment: [Try asking Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#ask). :)

Comment: The first part of the question (what's the advantage) basically has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/420683), whereas the second part (why have they been added) has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716426/420683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "copy constructors".

C++ is a value-based language. When you say `Foo x; Foo y = x;`, you need a way for `y` to have the same value as `x`. To do this, you need a copy constructor. The copy constructor has to take as an argument the `x` object, but it can't make a *copy* of it, since that's the very operation we're trying to define.

So it must take the argument by *reference*.

(You *could* have made copy constructors act weirdly and take an address, but that would be unexpected and make a mess of the language, especially given its evolution from the C language. A new type feature is a much cleaner and more powerful solution.)

Comment: Why could copy constructors not take pointers?

Comment: This is hardly the reason. The copy constructor could just as easily accept a pointer to the object to be duplicated.

Comment: Making a copy constructor take a pointer would have been unnatural and weird, and broken the "extension" quality of C++ compared to C. After all, it makes perfect sense to also have a constructor that actually takes a pointer.

Comment: I don't buy that it would be "unnatural and weird". It only seems that way because you're used to the (present) alternative.

Comment: I don't think this answer is particular good. It singles out *one* use for references, which could also be covered by pointers, and only provides a weak subjective reasoning for references being a better choice. -1

Comment: The question wasn't what references are good for, but why Bjarne added them. And this answer is as good as any to what he may have been thinking. +1.

Comment: If the copy ctor would take a pointer, the syntax would be `Foo y = &x;` or there had to be an implicit conversion.

Comment: DyP, there is already an implicit conversion to a reference type.

Comment: @devmac and an implicit conversion to pointer types will not follow the spec of `C` about pointers. Which was also a goal of `C++`.

Comment: StoryTeller, the implicit conversion only happens with copy constructors, which aren't a C feature. There wouldn't have been any breaking of C compatibility.

Comment: Well,I think it would just look weird to have pointers behave differently, even if it is solely with a new language feature.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it indicates that the object can't be null.

Second, it cant be assigned to point to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

reference is only referencing one object at his life it and it must have an object to reference (can't be null).

**In my believe** the creators of C++ was aiming to use only references (like C#) but have to allow the use of the pointers for two reasons: The references in C++ wasn't strong enough to have all the needed functionality and C++ was promised to have back comparability with C (every thing the C compile C++ compile)

Comment: References in C# (and similar things in other languages) *seem* like C++ references, but they're actually quite different. How much of this is due to the other differences in the execution model is up for debate, but in any case I doubt it's a helpful analogy.

Comment: I agree that the references in C++ and C# implementationlly and conceptually different BUT I believe that the original intention was the same just that in C++ they have constrains which prevent them from reaching the same thing.